A constructive proof of this innocent set theoretic proposition?
I was reading Freiwald's An Introduction to Set Theory and Topology, and I came across the following exercise from Chapter 1:

E8. Suppose $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are sets with $A\ne\emptyset$ and $B\ne\emptyset$.
Show that if
$$(A\times B)\cup (B\times A) = (C\times D)\cup(D\times C)\tag{1},$$
then either ($A = C$ and $B = D$) or ($A = D$ and $B = C$).

I prove this by contradiction, analyzing the following cases:

$\underline{a_0\in A\setminus C \text{ and } a_1\in A\setminus D}$:
Then due to nonemptiness of $B$ and Eq. (1), we get $a_0\in D$ and $a_1\in C$. Thus, $(a_0, a_1)\in D\times C$ and again by using (1), we get that one of $a_0$ or $a_1$, say $a_i$, is in $B$. Since $a_i\in A$ already, we have that $(a_i, a_i)\in A\times B$ so that by (1) again, we must have that $a_i\in C\cap D$, a contradiction.

$\underline{a_0\in A\setminus C \text{ and } d_0\in D\setminus A}$:
Then due to similar reasons as above, $d_0\in B$ so that $(a_0, d_0)\in A\times B$. Since $a_0\notin C$, we have $(a_0, d_0)\in D\times C$ so that $d_0\in C$. But then $(d_0, d_0)\in C\times D$ so that by (1), $d_0\in A$ – false.

$\underline{a_0\in A\setminus C \text{ and } b_0\in B\setminus C}$:
Then $(a_0, b_0)\in A\times B$ so that by (1), one of $a_0$ or $b_0$ must be in $C$, again false.


The rest of the cases are similar.
Question: Now, this above uses Double Negation Elimination (DNE) to prove what is a very innocent-looking proposition, which, it feels like, must be provable constructively. Any insights on this?

Consider the simple case $A \times B = C \times D$; we prove that if $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then $a \in C$ and $b \in D$, that means $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$ and then repeat with $a \in C$ and $b \in D$. Maybe you can use this approach managing the different cases...

To prove a disjunction, you may assume the negation of one of the terms. So here you can assume that (i) $A\neq\varnothing$, $B\neq\varnothing$; (ii) $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A) = (C\times D)\cup (D\times C)$; and (iii) either $A\neq C$ or $B\neq D$. And because $A$ and $B$ play symmetric roles, as do $C$ and $D$, you may just assume $A\neq C$. Then try proving directly that under these three assumptions, you have $A=D$ and $B=C$.

@ArturoMagidin not constructively: $\neg P \to \neg P$ (a tautology) does not imply $P \lor \neg P$.

@NaïmFavier Thanks; I think I misinterpreted "constructive" as "not by contradiction".

The proposition is a bit suspect constructively since it uses weak assumptions and concludes something strong. Specifically, something not being empty is typically a weaker assumption that you'd want. A better assumption is that $A$ and $B$ are inhabited, meaning that there exists an element of each set. Additionally, concluding a disjunction is strong because constructively proving such a thing means that it's possible to decide which one is true.
Indeed, the proposition as stated implies the law of excluded middle. As a preliminary, recall that the axiom of separation implies that the set $\{x \in X | P(x)\}$ exists whenever $P$ is a predicate on one variable. In particular, for any proposition $P$, $\{x \in X | P\}$ is a set. Classically, this set is either empty or all of $X$, so it typically isn't very interesting, but this kind of construction allows us to translate statements about sets to statements about propositions and vice versa. In particular, the propositions can be embedded as subsets of $1 = \{*\}$
Take $P$ and $Q$ to be two arbitrary propositions such that $P \land Q$ (that is, $P$ and $Q$) is not false (its double negation is true). Define $A = \{x \in 1 | P \land Q\}$, $B = 1$, $C = \{x \in 1 | P\}$ and finally $D = \{x \in 1 | Q\}$. $A$ is nonempty because the double negation of $P \land Q$ is true, and $B$ is trivially nonempty.
Then $A \times B = B \times A = C \times D = D \times C = A \times 1$. Thus the assumption that $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = (C \times D) \cup (D \times C)$ holds. By the proposition, we have $(A = C)$ and $(B = D)$ or $(A = D)$ and $(B = C)$.
$A = C$ and $B = D$ means that $P \land Q$ is true if and only if $P$ is true and that $Q$ is true. This simplifies to just saying that $Q$ is true, since if $Q$ is true, $P \land Q$ and $P$ are always equivalent.
$A = D$ and $B = C$ means that $P \land Q$ is true if and only if $Q$ is true and that $P$ is true. Again, this simplifies to just saying that $P$ is true.
Thus, our conclusion, under the assumption that $P \land Q$ is not false, is that $P \lor Q$ is true. Finally, taking $P = Q$ yields double negation elimination, which is equivalent to the law of excluded middle.

Let's first note that by assumption there are elements $a_0 \in A$ and $b_0 \in B$.
Lemma: If $(a_0, b_0) \in C \times D$ then $A = C$ and $B = D$.
Proof: Since we know that $a_0 \in C$ we have:
$$
\begin{align}
&b \in B \\
\implies
& (a_0, b) \in A \times B \\
\implies
& (a_0, b) \in (A \times B) \cup (B \times A ) \\
\implies 
& (a_0, b) \in (C \times D) \cup (D \times C) \\
\implies
& (a_0, b) \in C \times D \; \lor \; (a_0, b) \in D \times C \\
\stackrel{a_0 \in C}{\implies}
& (a_0, b) \in C \times D \\
\implies 
& b \in D
\end{align}
$$
And therefore $B \subseteq D$. The same kind of argument works to show $D \subseteq B$. We therefore have $B = D$. Likewise, by making use of the fact that $b_0 \in D$ we can show $A = D$. $\Box$
Of course the positions of $C, D$ can easily be swapped in the above lemma, so we also have:
$$
(a_0, b_0) \in D \times C \implies A = D \land B = C.
$$
To finish the proof of the result in question we now simply need to note that
$$
\begin{align}
& (a_0, b_0) \in A \times B \\
\implies
& (a_0, b_0) \in (A \times B) \cup (B \times A ) \\
\implies 
& (a_0, b_0) \in (C \times D) \cup (D \times C) \\
\implies 
& (a_0, b_0) \in C \times D \; \lor \; (a_0, b_0) \in D \times C \\
\stackrel{\text{Lemma}}{\implies} 
& (A = C \land B = D) \lor (A = D \land B = C)
\end{align} 
$$

The step involving $a_0 \in C$ in the lemma is not correct; you'd need to know $a_0 \notin D$. Also, as a nitpick, the question as stated only assumes that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, not inhabited (but then I think the theorem is nonconstructive).

@NaïmFavier Yes you are right! I'll try to see if I can salvage the proof of the lemma. Regarding the nonempty-ness I would indeed also argue that in a proper constructive formulation would use "inhabited" instead of "nonempty".

@NaïmFavier I'd be very surprised if this could be proved constructively when $A$ and $B$ are not assumed to be inhabited but only nonempty.

Yeah, that's what I was trying to say.

OP is asking for Insights/Alternatives/Outlines :
Suggestion 1 :
Consider some $(x,y)$ occurs on LHS.
That implies that $(x \in A \land y \in B) \lor (x \in B \land y \in A)\tag{A}$
We are given that $(x,y)$ occurs on RHS too.
That implies that $(x \in C \land y \in D) \lor (x \in D \land y \in C)\tag{B}$
We have to manipulate (A) & (B) to show the Conclusion given.
Suggestion 2 :
It is easy to see that :
$(x \in A \lor x \in B) \iff (x \in C \lor x \in D)$
$(y \in A \lor y \in B) \iff (y \in C \lor y \in D)$
In other words $A \cup B \equiv C \cup D$
Suggestion 3 :
We might take $x \in A \setminus B$ & $y \in B \setminus A$
Then $(x,x)$ & $(y,y)$ will not occur.
Naturally , $x$ & $y$ can not occur in $C \cap D$
We then get :
$x \in [C \setminus D] \cup [D \setminus C]$
$y \in [C \setminus D] \cup [D \setminus C]$
Suggestion 4 :
Take $x_1$ & $x_2$ occuring $A \setminus B$
Let that $x_1$ occur in $C \setminus D$ , then show that $x_2$ must also occur in $C \setminus D$
Hence $A=C$
Take $x_1$ & $x_2$ occuring $A \setminus B$
Let that $x_1$ occur in $D \setminus C$ , then show that $x_2$ must also occur in $D \setminus C$
Hence $A=D$
Suggestion 5 :
Due to Symmetry , that argument will work to show that $B=C$ or $B=D$.
Over-all , that Outline will complete the Proof.
SUMMARY :
I am attempting the outline to show the Conclusion using $A \setminus B$ , $A \cup B$ , $A \cap B$ , $B \setminus A$ on LHS , which must match up with $C \setminus D$ , $C \cup D$ , $C \cap D$ , $D \setminus C$ on RHS , in some order.
The Crux is that $(x,x)$ occurs if and only if $x \in A \cap B$ which demands $x \in C \cap D$
ADDENDUM :
This is very round-about , because we are looking to get "Constructive" Proof , without using DNE (Double Negation Elimination) & PEM (Principle of Excluded Middle) & Etc.

In Suggestion 3, you write $x$ and $y$ can't occur in $C\cap D$. Can you prove that without using proof by contradiction?

When $x$ occurs in $C \cap D$ , then $C \times D$ can have $(x,x)$ , while $A \times B$ can not have $(x,x)$ , hence $LHS$ can not Equal $RHS$ , @Atom , though it will require knowing what Axioms & Definitions we are using for two Sets to be Equal or not.

I don't think the issue here is of alternate definitions/axioms. What you are reasoning is as follows (correct me if I am wrong): Assuming $x\in C\cap D$ yields you a contradiction (that LHS ≠ RHS), so you deduce that $x\notin C\cap D$.

But that is just proof by contradiction (see PBC here).

Valid Onbjection , @Atom , I might have to rethink the matter !
